# Validate a number mixed with a letter

Tags: excel

I have a column in an Excel sheet which requires a number of the following format: A978945. The first character will always be a letter the rest six characters will always be numbers between 0 to 9 inclusively.

How can I validate to make sure that every entry in that column is of that format?

I have tried "@000000" and "@######" without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming cell A1 is the range in question, select it and for Data Validation enter this formula under Custom:

```
=AND(LEN(A1)=7,ISTEXT(A1),ISNUMBER(MID(A1,2,6)+0))
```

Comment: its the whole column that requires the validation. How do I make it span the whole column?

Comment: First select entire column by clicking the column label at the top of the worksheet. Then go into the Data Validation dialog and enter the formula. If you want this for column A, the formula is ready to go... don't change a thing. Once confirmed Excel automatically adjust the formula changing the references to the appropriate row all the way down. If you want this for a different column then you will need to edit the column references (the A's) in my formula; but leave them all pointing to row 1.